# Access violation reading location 9x03F20D84 (Visual Studio C++)

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2017

I get an exception (access violation) when using cvtColor() in the code below, also it says opencv_imgproc249d.pdb not loaded. The code looks like this:

```
    void Bildverarbeitung::run()
    {
        *CameraPicture = PylonBibObj->loadFrameColor();
        tempMatCol = CameraPicture->getCameraPicture();
        cvtColor(tempMatCol, HSVImage2, CV_BGR2HSV);
        imshow("tempMatCol", tempMatCol);
    }
```

The code works fine until cvtColor but then an Exception is thrown and the  opencv_imgproc249d.pdb not loaded appears. I already checked the Linkers and they seem to be correct. In the Bildverarbeitung-header-file I'm including:

```
    #include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
    #include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>

    class Bildverarbeitung
    { 
    public: 
        Bildverarbeitung();
        ~Bildverarbeitung();
    private:
        Bild* CameraPicture;
        PylonBib* PylonBibObj;
        void fnInit();
    };
extern Bildverarbeitung* bilderkennung;
```

The Bildverarbeitung Constructor looks like this:

```
Bildverarbeitung::Bildverarbeitung()
{
    CameraPicture = new Bild();
    PylonBibObj = new PylonBib();
    fnInit();
}
```

CameraPicture is a pointer to the type Bild.
The PylonBib.cpp code looks like this:

```
#include "PylonBib.h"

PylonBib::PylonBib(void)
{
}

PylonBib::~PylonBib(void)
{
    PylonBib::beendeGrabbing();
    m_cameraPyl->DestroyDevice();
    delete m_cameraPyl;
    Pylon::PylonTerminate();
}

void PylonBib::Init()
{
    using namespace GenApi;
    Pylon::PylonInitialize();
        try {
            IPylonDevice* pDevice = CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice();   //CInstantCamera camera = CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice();                                                                            //create PylonCamera Objekt
            m_cameraPyl = new CInstantCamera(pDevice);
            cout << "Using Device: " << m_cameraPyl->GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName() << endl;
            m_cameraPyl->StartGrabbing(GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly, GrabLoop_ProvidedByUser);
            // Hearbeat Timeout um zu verhindern, dass die Kamera 5 Minuten auf eine Antwort des Programms
            // wartet (Standard zu Debug zwecken). Daher geändert um nicht warten zu müssen.
            GenApi::CIntegerPtr m_pHeartbeatTimeout;
            m_pHeartbeatTimeout = m_cameraPyl->GetTLNodeMap().GetNode("HeartbeatTimeout");
            m_pHeartbeatTimeout->SetValue(1000);
            successfullInitialized = true;
            cout << "Successfull Initialized!" << endl;
    }
    catch (GenICam::GenericException &e){                                   // Error handling.
        cout << "An Exception Occurred: " << endl << e.GetDescription() << endl;
    }
}

void PylonBib::beendeGrabbing()
{   
    m_cameraPyl->StopGrabbing();
}

Bild PylonBib::ladeFrameColor(){

    try {
        while (m_cameraPyl->IsGrabbing()) {
            m_cameraPyl->RetrieveResult(500, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);
            if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded()) {
                formatConverter.Convert(pylonImage, ptrGrabResult);
                Mat openCVImage = cv::Mat(ptrGrabResult->GetHeight(), ptrGrabResult->GetWidth(), CV_8UC3, (uint8_t *)pylonImage.GetBuffer());
                Bild cameraPicture1;
                cameraPicture1.setCameraPicture(openCVImage);
                ptrGrabResult.Release();
                return cameraPicture1;
            }
            else {
                cout << "ERROR OpenCVImage2:" << ptrGrabResult->GetErrorCode() << ptrGrabResult->GetErrorDescription() << endl;
            }
        }
    }   
    catch (GenICam::GenericException &e) {
        // Error handling.
        std::cerr << "An exception occurred. -> in PylonBib: ladeFrame" << endl << e.GetDescription() << endl;
    }
    Bild rueckgabeBild;
    return rueckgabeBild;
}
```

and the pylonBib-Header-File is the following:

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

#include <pylon\PylonIncludes.h>
#include <pylon\PylonGUI.h>
#include "Bild.h"

using namespace Pylon;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


class PylonBib
{
public:
    PylonBib(void);
    PylonBib(const PylonBib &right);
    PylonBib& operator= (PylonBib &right);
    ~PylonBib(void);
    Bild ladeFrameColor();
    void Init();
    CInstantCamera *m_cameraPyl;
private:
    bool successfullInitialized;
    void beendeGrabbing();
    CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;
    CImageFormatConverter formatConverter;
    CPylonImage pylonImage;
};
```

The Bild class looks like this now:

```
class Bild
{
public:
    Bild(void);
    Bild(Mat image);
    Bild& operator=(Mat& rhs)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    ~Bild();

    Mat getCameraPicture();
    void setCameraPicture(Mat image);

private:
    Mat Picture;
};
```

The Main-function looks like this:

```
#include "Bildverarbeitung.h"

//https://www.baslerweb.com/fp-1476182890/media/downloads/documents/application_notes/AW00136101000_Getting_Started_with_pylon4_and_OpenCV.pdf

int main()
{
    bilderkennung->run();
}
```

Can anyone help me? I haven't found a solution for this on the internet.
Thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: What is `CameraPicture`? Where does it point?

Comment: Its probably a good idea to fire up the debugger and see what is returned from loadFrameColor/getCameraPicture

Comment: I edited the post. @Someprogrammerdude.

Comment: You still haven't show us where `CameraPicture` is pointing. You *do* make it point somewhere? You do have e.g. `CameraPicture = new Bild;` (or something similar) somewhere? If you don't make it point anywhere, then it will be pointing to an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) location, leading to *undefined behavior* when you dereference the pointer. And that's the most likely reason for your crash.

Comment: I added the Bildverarbeitung constructor. @Someprogrammerdude
The run() function is called from an object of type Bildverarbeitung.

Comment: The it depends a lot on the `Bild` class. Does it follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) properly? This is very important since you return and copy objects. Same thing with the `Bildverarbeitung` class of course. Since you have a destructor, then you should follow those rules.

Comment: I wasn't doing that. I had to add the copy constructor and the copy assignement operator (as you can see above now). I hope I am doing this correct. Thanks a lot, but unfortunately the error remains the same :( @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I just added the last code parts. So maybe now someone can help me?